# Ajax call no longer hitting controller

Tags: c#, ajax

I have to following code which is making an ajax call:

```
function openMapTab(lat, lng) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/DisplayMap?qid=" + $('body').data('usid'),
    data: {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
    },
    dataType: "text",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.head).html("<title>Arcania-Maps</title>");
        $(w.document.body).html(data);
    },
});
}
```

My controller is as below:

```
public ActionResult DisplayMap(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        ViewBag.Latitude = latitude;
        ViewBag.Longitude = longitude;
        return View();
    }
```

However for some reason my ajax call is not hitting the action even though this was the case earlier.
Any idea why?

Comment: What http status is being returned when you looked at Chrome Developer tools Network tab?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. For example, it seems odd that your controller is called `ControllerController`.

Comment: What is the value of `$('body').data('usid')`?

Comment: Please go back (in git or whatever is your source control system) to when it did work, and update your question to include that code so we can try and spot the difference.

Comment: `url: "/Controller/DisplayMap?qid=" + $('body').data('usid')` => this is not a right way to define URL for POST request, because POST request doesn't use query string like that. Consider create [mcve] snippet and explain how the action method is never hit.

Answer (score 0):

All controller actions are `GET` by default. So if you want to process `POST` requests then you need to add `[HttpPost]`-attribute.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ActionResult DisplayMap(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    ...
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yes, it's possible to return `ActionResult` here. https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1